# How to decrement an entire csv column with Python - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

I am very new to programming so please be patient with me.

I am reading from a .csv like so:

```
1, -2
2, 3
3, -6
4, 5
5, 7
```

and so on.  My goal here, essentially is just to delete the first row, and then decrement the remaining first column by 1, so I'd have something like..

```
1, 3
2, -6
3, 5
4, 7
5, *some randomly generated number*
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
del data[0] 

for i in range(len(data)):

  newTime = data[i][0] - 1
  oldNum = data[0][1]
  data.insert(i, [newTime, oldNum])
```

however this is just taking 1, 3 and inserting it len(data) times.. what am I doing wrong?  Please don't be mean, I really am trying to learn!

I was using this as guidance: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html, and to me it seems like this should work.. :/ Haaaalp!

Comment: could you provide the code that reads the csv too? Makes it easier for testing

Comment: I've added it, sorry, I once did that and someone yelled at me about it.. but there ya go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

data = [[1,2], 
        [2,4], 
        [3,-5], 
        [4,9], 
        [5,7]]

l = len(data)

for i in range(l-1):
    data[i][1] = data[i+1][1]

data[l-1][1] = random.randint(-3,3)

print(data)
```

output:

```
[[1, 4], 
[2, -5], 
[3, 9], 
[4, 7], 
[5, 0]]
```

Comment: this didn't do anything at all when I ran it.. :/

Comment: @rita Is the structure of your `data` like the one I posted?

Comment: my bad... I had a line that wasn't supposed to be there still hanging out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Commenting on the posted code, I don't understand why it would use a csv library to read all the lines out of a file and then split the lines with lower level methods. Doing too much will cause bugs, even for experts.  Let the library or framework do as much as it can for you and make your own code reasonably short.

A modern library for data is [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which includes [support for reading various data file formats including CSV](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html).

Here's how one could read in a csvfile with a column "name", subset the file data name>=2, deduct one from name, and write it back out.

Tested as shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import random
DIN = pd.read_csv("csvfile.csv")
DOUT = DIN[DIN['name']>=2]
DOUT['name']=DOUT['name']-1
DOUT = pd.concat([DOUT, pd.DataFrame({'name': DOUT['name'].tail(1)+1, 'value': int(random.random()*100)})])
DOUT.to_csv("newcsvfile.csv", index=False)
```

in

```
"name","value"
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,4
7,3
8,2
9,1
```

out

```
name,value
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
5,4
6,3
7,2
8,1
9,76
```

Comment: ... and augment with random value row

Comment: @rickhg12hs adding rows a bit painful in pandas but doable

Answer (score 2):

Using the built-in `csv` module, this is trivial. The trick is to convert the data you are getting in (which are strings) into numbers before you decrement stuff.

```
import csv
from random import randrange

with open('data.csv') as inf, open('out.csv','w') as out:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(next(reader)) # read the first line and write it
                                  # to the output file
    next(reader) # skips the first row
    rows = list(reader) # grab all the rows
    for row in rows:
       row[0] = int(row[0])-1 # reduce the first number for all
                              # rows
    # Set the last row to a random number
    rows.append([max(row[0] for rows in row)+1,randrange(10)])
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: ... and the final row?

Comment: Don't forget to append the annoying random value row.

Comment: Final row needs to be appended here, no?